# Combining 2 Databases (mySQL and Azure)

Tags: mysql, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I'm hosting a Website where i have 2 GB storag espace where i currently store ints and strings, i want to be able to upload thousands images  into the database so i thought about using Azure for storing the images as blobs how should i combine it so that i can for example link i primary key from MySQL to a image i stored in Azure?

Or is there any other way? would love if i got links to read more about it!

is this a solution?

```
CREATE TABLE `T1`(`A` VARCHAR(100),UNIQUE KEY(`A`(30))) ENGINE=FEDERATED
  CONNECTION='MYSQL://127.0.0.1:3306/TEST/T1';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i want to be able to upload thousands images into the database
```

If I'm understanding this correctly, you want to store images as blobs inside a db (column)?

It's not a great idea to be storing images as blobs in DB for many reasons. It just doesn't make sense that you need to make a DB call to render an image when we have storage engines like AWS S3 , Azure Storage (S3 alternative) and many more.

Better approach is to store your files metadata such as file name, endpoint etc in your database and have the file stored in an appropriate storage that I've mentioned above.

Good luck.

Comment: How do i do that? is there any good documentation i can read or watch? how do i link the databses together?